# Are Containers and Kubernetes IaaS or PaaS?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, cloud

Since we don't need to configure most of the Infrastructure services for Containers and Kubernetes, still we have ability to manage different Infrastructure services.
Does this make them Infrastructure as a Service or Platform as a Service?

Comment: What helps me level set the difference is something like EC2 is IaaS whereas something like Beanstalk is a PaaS

Answer (score 9):

kubernetes is considered PaaS when the control p[lane components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-clusters-workloads): the scheduler, the API server, ETCD (key-value metadata)and controller are managed by the provider
some examples are Microsoft  [AKS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/kubernetes-service/), Google [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine), AWS [EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc&eks-blogs.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&eks-blogs.sort-order=desc).
It is considered IaaS if you built and maintain all the components

Answer (score 5):

Kubernetes is neither IaaS nor PaaS. It's a container orchestration engine which makes it more like a Container As A Service or CaaS.

You need a IaaS layer below kubernetes to provide it VMs like for example AWS EC2 or bare metal servers.

Kubernetes can be used as a platform for building Platform As a Service on top of it and [CloudFoundry on Kubernetes](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-for-k8s) is an example of a PaaS built on kubernetes.

Answer (score 2):

I have to dissent a bit with the answer here above.
All technical definitions are quite meticolous, but are often a model to explain what's in place, and so they can change over time or overlap a bit.

A couple of years ago there was no "Container as a Service" or "CaaS" whatsoever. Container platforms, were just called "PaaS", or "Platform as a Service".
At some point "PaaS" became ambiguous because there were many platforms usable by developers that fit "PaaS" definition: amongst these PaaS techonolgies, some were in turn running on Kubernetes platform, which was also defined as PaaS.

Somebody felt the need to distinguish the two concepts in order to better communicate with developers if they had to choose between a more abstract platform, or to directly rely upon container orchestration (most widespread Kubernetes).
So, distinction between PaaS and CaaS was introduced.

This is how it happened that in previous definition Kubernetes and container orchestration in general were defined simply as "PaaS". And nowadays they are called "CaaS".

Instead Infrastructure as a Service, or simply "IaaS", is the infrastructure layer upon which Kubernetes runs: namely the virtual machine instances into which the Kubernetes nodes are implemented, the network connectivity part, and other basic elements.

Beware: happens that these definitions are used in a different manner over time by **VENDORS**, that tend to mix a bit of commercial pushing (i.e. towards a new product) into what is presented just as a technical overview article. Don't be fooled! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes official site says "Kubernetes is not a traditional, all-inclusive PaaS (Platform as a Service) system."

visit : [https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/#:~:text=Kubernetes%20is%20not%20a%20traditional,Platform%20as%20a%20Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/#:%7E:text=Kubernetes%20is%20not%20a%20traditional,Platform%20as%20a%20Service))%20system.